# Функция Javascript для подставления данных

Tags: javascript, html, функции, google-maps-api, yandex-maps-api

Подскажите, пожалуйста, есть массив элементов с координатами на google maps. Присуствует infowindow, я знаю то, что при помощи такого вида ссылки передаются данные в яндекс-навгитор. yandexmaps://maps.yandex.ru/?ll=37.62,55.75&z=12
Хочу написать функцию, которая бы брала данные координат из массива и подставляла в данную ссылку, как лучше это реализовать?

Comment: В чем собственно проблема? Прогоняем массив через цикл и формируем урл. Ну или я что-то не так понял...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> yandexmaps://maps.yandex.ru/?ll=37.62,55.75&z=12 Хочу написать функцию, которая бы брала данные координат из массива и подставляла в данную ссылку, как лучше это реализовать?

```js
// Допустим массив выглядит так
var arr = [
  [37.62, 55.75, 12],
  [31.62, 54.75, 15]
];
// Собираем результат
var urls = [];
// Проходим по координатам
arr.forEach(function(u, i) {
  // Координата собранна в ссылку
  let url = `yandexmaps://maps.yandex.ru/?ll=${u[0]},${u[1]}&z=${u[2]}`;
  // Добавляем в массив
  urls[i] = url;
})

console.log(urls);
```

Comment: Большое спасибо!

Comment: @AndronioSunrise [Чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ или отметьте его как решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)